# Why changes made on a branch are shown on another?

Tags: git

I was working on branch **A** and had done some changes, Commit locally those changes but not pushed. Then I need to fix one urgent issue, switched to another branch **B** and done some changes their, and commit those changes and pushed.

When I see my log at branch **B**, it was showing one file changes that was commited in branch **A** instead of branch **B**.

```
Commands that I have executed.
$git status          // shows the 2 files that was changed in branch A
$git add -A          // add those 2 files that was changed.
$git commit -m "intermediate commit"         // need to push later when my current feature will be completed.
$git checkout branch B     // switched to second branch
$git status            // one file that was changed in branch B
$git add -A       // add that file
$git commit -m "imediate issue is fixed"
$git push origin B   // push those changes.
```

See the log in branch **B** there was two files changed, one that was changed in branch **A** and one that was changed in branch **B**.

Why my branch **A** changes reflected in branch **B**?

Comment: How did you "switch to another branch B"?

Comment: Was that file changed in both A and B?

Comment: I used the command **git checkout B**, for switching.

Comment: Can you list the commands you did?

Comment: @jcm: sure. let me edit the question.

Comment: @merlin2011: yeah that file was changed in both A and B.

Comment: Were there any commits on A that *did not* show up on B?

Comment: yeah, there is different feature in branch A, that contains only that feature realted changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to get around this question is by invoking `gitk` in your branch B. This will display the commit tree of the branch. You will see when this file change was performed, either directly in branch B or if it was pushed by A and how.

Maybe a file simply slipped your attention, but it's hard for us to say what happened exactly without looking at the commit tree and without the exact commands you performed.

Comment: `gitk --all` wiil do it.

Comment: @jcm: when I run the above command, it shows both files that was changed. second file shows that comment, **deleted file mode 100644
index ce5ebd2..0000000**, but I have not done these changes anyhow in branch **B**